# Prove that the following quotients are isomorphic

Tags: category-theory, modules, quotient-spaces, module-isomorphism

I am preparing myself for an upcoming exam, and I've found the following problem

> Let $M$ be a $R$-module and $N_1 \subset N_2 \subset M$ be $A$-submodules. Use the Snake Lemma to show that $$\frac{M/N_1}{N_2/N_1} \cong \frac{M}{N_2}.$$

I have tried several different setups to use the Snake Lemma and prove this result. However, none of them seem to work. Could anyone please point out how I should start?

---

**Edit:** The [Snake Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma) states that, in an abelian category, given the following commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
@. A @>{f}>> B @>{g}>> C @> >> 0\\
@. @V{a}VV @V{b}VV @V{c}VV\\
0 @>>> A' @>{f'}>> B' @>{g'}>> C'
\end{CD}
in which the rows are exact sequences and $0$ is the zero object, one has the following exact sequence
$$\operatorname{Ker}(a) \rightarrow \operatorname{Ker}(b) \rightarrow \operatorname{Ker}(c) \xrightarrow{d} \operatorname{Coker}(a) \rightarrow \operatorname{Coker}(b) \rightarrow \operatorname{Coker}(c)$$
with $d$ a homomorphism.

Comment: What is the Skane Lemma? Snake lemma?

Comment: I have updated the question, @cansomeonehelpmeout

Comment: I see! I thought "Skane lemma", as in "Use the Skane Lemma to show that (...)" was something, else! I applaud you tho, for taking the time to construct that diagram!

Comment: I noticed just now that it was written "Skane" instead of Snake, both in the question and in your comment. It was a typo, sorry.

Comment: The accepted answer gives a nice explanation of how to use the Snake Lemma to prove this isomorphism, but I wanted to point out that there is a much simpler proof (in case you don't know it). Just map $M/N_1$ to $M/N_2$ by $m+N_1\mapsto m+N_2$, observe that this map is surjective with kernel $N_2/N_1$, and use the first isomorphism theorem to conclude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0@>>> N_2 @>>> M @>>> \frac M{N_2} @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> \frac{N_2}{N_1} @>>> \frac M{N_1} @>>> \frac{M/N_1}{N_2/N_1} @>>>0
\end{CD}
The rows are the usual exact sequence associated to a quotient modules, the first two vertical arrows are canonical and commutativity as well as the existence of the latter vertical arrow follow from the homomorphism theorem. Let $\varphi$ be the last vertical arrow.

Now apply the Snake lemma, or rather as slightly upgraded version thereof. As you can see we have short exact sequences rather than only right and left, respectively, exact rows. One can show (quite easily) that in this case the Snake Lemma is sequence is exact at $\ker a$ and $\operatorname{coker} c$ too. Using this we see that there are exact sequences $0\to N_1\to N_1\to\ker\varphi\to0$ and $0\to\operatorname{coker}\varphi\to0$ implying that $\ker\varphi=0=\operatorname{coker}\varphi$. This in turn is equivalent to $\varphi$ being an isomorphism as desired.